# How to recover healthy HDD Windows file system if it was re-initialised

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

I had 2 x HDDs on RAID1 on Marvell controller on old m/b

I've built new PC on different m/b. It has U2 support which kills RAID, so I bought Marvell based PCIe card with 2 ports.

I connected the disks to Marvell. There was no RAID but I could see the data.

I disconnected them and connected to the m/b secondary SATA controller which is As(s)media.

And Windows stopped to recognise the new disks. I found they need "initialisation" in the Disk Management panel.

I did stupid thing and initialised them.

Now they appear to be empty. I did not create new partitions on them.

I guess it must be trivial to recover the data. But I know this data recovery market is greatly obfuscated by the vendors to inflate prices for the software/services

I need a practical advice from a savvy person.

**Whats the best (cleanest and cheapest) way to restore the file system in my situation?**

Comment: Take it to a professional.

Comment: you will need another disk of equal or greater size (if thats what you mean by cheapest) but I'd start with TestDisk. Since no data was overwritten, it shouldn't have too much trouble finding and recovering your partition.

Comment: umm. yes i dont think its difficult to recover.. i just need to find the right tool.. that was the question.

Comment: @Xavierjazz i once mucked up RAID5 in a similar fashion. I took it to a professional (recommended by our IT manager). they charged me 600 quid and restored about 20% of data.. I didnt hammer the disks. I just moved them from one PC to another... so thank you but no thank you

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271

Comment: If you've done something similar before... you'd think this time you'd have had a backup :/

Comment: RAID5 is quite a bit differant than RAID1, in that an entire copy of the data should be present on each disk on a RAID1 volume, so you only need to recover from one disk to get the whole volume. no stripping or other complexities. Testdisk is probably right for you: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk . just make sure you recover to another disk.

Comment: thanks Frank. why dont you put it as an answer.. i am running undelete scan atm. but will try test disk after that

Comment: @tetsujin i have 2 x 2tb raids. its hard to backup.. however i have backup of about 30% of data.. so the loss is not critical.. but given that deleted partition shouldnt be not too hard to recover (as many agreed with me) id like to try and recover it first..

Answer (score 0):

As I expected it was really not a big deal at all.. I used free version of Undelete (which took more than 2hr to scan 2Tb disk) but the recovering of the partition took **less than a second.**

While it was scanned I also found EaseUS Partition Recovery (which found the partition immediately but I didnt try to recover as undeleted was under way).

And @Frank Thomas suggested TestDisk which I havent tried but it looked promising..

So - for all the future references (and to salute to all the idiots like me) - dont be afraid of asking question. Dont buy grumpy "IT professionals" advices (take it to the vet)..